# spark structured streaming spark.ui.enabled true has serious impact on my application

Tags: apache-spark

We are using spark version 3.2.2
We have a spark structured streaming application with about 80 streams running in parallel.
When using spark.ui.enabled=true , our application has micro batch duration taking longer and longer until hanging.

Why spark.ui.enabled=true has so much impact on our application ?
Could the settings of spark.ui.* parameters have a benefit in this problematic (https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.2/configuration.html) ?

When using spark.ui.enabled=false , our application runs smoothly.